# Dialog reloading Partial - JQuery doesn't work (MVC 3)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

When I open dialog all things work correct but when I close dialog and I try open this again I have got problem with JQuery (animation, hide etc.) Probably **Partial View** all the time is working and when dialog is showed again it doesn't mean **Partial View** is also new. How to fix it?

This doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#bladReje').hide();
    $('#bladRejeText').hide();
    $('#poprawnieReje').hide();
    $('#poprawnieRejeText').hide();
</script>
```

Partial

```
 data.View
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Reje", "Log")',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {

                    var el1 = $('<div><strong style="color: black">' + data.View + '</strong></div>');
                    $(el1).dialog(
                        {
                            modal: true,
                            title: '<div></div>',
                            minWidth: 340,
                            minHeight: 300,
                            buttons: {
                                'close': function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("destroy");
                                }
                            }
                        });
                }

            }
            });    
    });
```

This is example of my **Partial View**

```
<div id="bladReje" style="padding: 0px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 auto; text-align: left; 
font-family: arial; visibility:hidden;">
    <div id="bladRejeText" style="font-size: 16px; visibility:hidden;">
    </div>
</div>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Example, new { style = "width:220px" })
<input type="button" class="button" value="Zapisz" onclick="SaveRejestracja();" style="float: right; margin-right: 30px;"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#bladReje').hide();
    $('#bladRejeText').hide();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function SaveRejestracja() {
        var Example = $('#Example').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Example", "ControllerExample")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                Nick: Example
            },
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            async: false,
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    $('#bladReje').hide();
                    $('#bladReje').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                    $('#bladRejeText').hide();
                    $('#bladRejeText').css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                }
                if (!data.Success) {
                    $('#bladReje').hide();
                    $('#bladReje').css({ visibility: "visible" });
                    $('#bladRejeText').hide();
                    $('#bladRejeText').css({ visibility: "visible" });
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

This work only first time

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#bladReje').hide();
    $('#bladRejeText').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: Try using `$(this).dialog("close");` instead of `$(this).dialog("destroy");`

Comment: this will not help believe me I try this before

Comment: Could you provide more code? I mean, when is that AJAX request called? Do you have any scripts that run on page ready? What are all those `hide` calls?

Comment: @Andre Calil  I open only Partial in partial I have got all JS

Comment: Man, I can't understand what you're saying. By Partial you mean a **Partial View** or something that you got using an **AJAX Call**?

Comment: @Andre Calil Partial View -> sorry for this. I should write partial view.

Comment: I see why you feel it's unnecessary to post your partials, but at least one example of partial rendered with div container would help

Comment: @Dave A  I added example can you look?

Comment: why are you calling `destroy` method? that removes the dialog and its functionality. I would expect you to use `close`...

Comment: @ Dave A close I have got before :) now I try destroy but doesn`t work. Maybe you know some function to refresh partial view into dialog? refresh(data.View)

Comment: Why don't you try wrapping it in the jquery document.ready() function?